# How to make access query criteria in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to stop a name from appearing in a listbox that is linked to a query. The listbox shows records and fields from a table.
I am unable to just type the following in the criteria field:

```
Not "Administration"
```

or

```
<> "Administration
```

I am not sure why but I think it might work if i add it in code instead. How do I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably the field contains invisible characters or leading/trailing spaces. You can check this easily if you change the criteria to `= "Administration"`. If query returns no rows, the data is not exactly equal. You can try criteria `Not Like "*Administration*"`, but this way may not work for all data. Correct condition is `<> "Administration"`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I added `= "Administration"` in the criteria but it just ignored it and showed everything as if I hadn't typed a thing into the criteria. Same again for the other criteria you mentioned.

Comment: Please show the text of you SQL query, look like it's something else. Add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the listbox RowSource property, as follows:

1- show the listbox properties window

2- go to RowSource property under 'Data' Tab

3- click the button next to RowSource property (which will open a Query Editor window)

4- Add the condition:
 Trim([ColumnName])<>"Administration"

where you replace **ColumnName** with your actual *column name*

I hope this helps out.

*(Sorry I'm still using an older MS-Access release nevertheless you should get the idea).*